# Infinite series involving factorials of squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Does

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n^2)!}=2.04167\dots$$

possess a closed form?

Comment: I doubt it. On the upside it converges really fast. You only need to go to $n=3$ to get the sum to an accuracy of $10^{-14}$.

Comment: I doubt too. May I ask in which context you faced this sum ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I noticed that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)^2} = I_0(2)$$ is a Bessel function, so I wondered whether a similar expression in terms of special (or elementary) functions exists if the two operations are reversed.

Comment: I did not find anything. Sorry for that ! To go on the dame way as Winther, using $n=5$, the first $100$ digits are correct.